# How to call c# server side method through javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I need to call a c# server method through the javascript. I have a gridview in which i have a column with dropdown list. When i change the dropdown's value i need to call a server side method through javascript and change the value of another text box in the gridview.

I am able to do this on the selected index change. but i am slightly worried about the performance.

i am using asp.net c#.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to call a servers side method to change the value of a textbox?  Or are those two independent actions?

Comment: Wrap the GridView in an UpdatePanel. It will probably be good enough...if not at least you only spent 2 minutes adding an UpdatePanel.

Comment: @Romanarmy:  my intention is to improve the performance of my page. Suppose if the user changes textbox value or drodpwnlist, it may take sometime to hit the server because of the viewstate. I dont wanna do that.on the textbox change i need to calculate few thing on that row.
@Paper1337: Even though if i put the gridview in the updatepanel,i wont get performance.
Suppose i have around 100 rows in the griview. at this point of time response time will be more,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can also use PageMethods with ajax like here

http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use AJAX in a manner similar to this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Ajax_Samplecode_in_C_Net.aspx